# Node.js: Error: spawn ENOENT while using GM module

Tags: javascript, node.js, graphicsmagick

Even though this has been asked several times, none of the existing answers helped me out. Using a MEAN environment (on Mac OSX), I installed graphicsmagick using:

```
sudo npm install gm
```

Whenever I run the following script, I get this error:

```
{ [Error: spawn ENOENT] code: 'ENOENT', errno: 'ENOENT', syscall: 'spawn' }
```

This is the piece of code I am trying to run:

```
var gm = require('gm');    
//var gm = require('gm').subClass({ imageMagick: true }); //tried this one too 

    gm('./project/public/images/webshots/test1.jpg')
           .resize(320, 240)
           .write('./project/public/images/webshots/test2.jpg', function (err) {
        if (!err) console.log('done');
        if(err){
           console.log(err);   
        }
        });
```

Appropriate writing permissions were given by:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 ./project/public/images/webshots
```

I even tried several source/destination path combinations. What else could I have missed?

Comment: Did you install imagemagick/graphicsmagick first as noted in the `gm` [readme](https://github.com/aheckmann/gm#getting-started)? If so, are you able to execute imagemagick/graphicsmagick manually from the shell prompt?

Comment: Yes, both were installed. Sorry for asking but how can I execute it manually?

Comment: For graphicsmagick it's just `gm`.

Comment: No, I can't start it manually. Getting the error: no such command. Maybe I need to set a PATH?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `gm` module can't find the path to the `gm` executable. So it sounds like your `$PATH` needs to be updated to include the path where graphicsmagick was installed to.

Comment: I took those steps: reinstalled gm (sudo npm install gm) AND added /node_modules/gm to my PATH information (vim /etc/paths) but I still can neither run gm manually (same error as before) nor run my code (same error).

Comment: First of all, you shouldn't use `sudo` to install locally, just use `npm install gm`. The other issue is that I wasn't referring to the `gm` **module** being in your `PATH`, but the actual path to the `gm` **binary** (this is totally separate from the `gm` module in npm). The `gm` **binary** is the one you install from homebrew, macports, or compile and install from [source](http://sourceforge.net/projects/graphicsmagick/files/graphicsmagick/) for example. The `gm` npm module calls out to the `gm` **binary**, so the module won't work until the **binary** is installed properly.

Comment: Thank you for that important clarification! I totally got lost here, as I thought I was handling an "ordinary" node module. Now that I am aware that I am (also) dealing with actual binaries that must be installed separately (not using npm!) I got it working now. Thanks again and sorry for goofing up.

Comment: But How to install those binaries?

Answer (score 5):

It is looking for the gm(GraphicsMagick) binary

Install GraphicsMagick via PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:dhor/myway
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install graphicsmagick
```

This worked for me

Answer (score 1):

This helped me solving this issue.

```
gm('./project/public/images/webshots/test1.jpg')
.options({imageMagick: true})
.resize(320, 240)
.write('./project/public/images/webshots/test2.jpg', function (err) {
    if (!err) console.log('done');
    if(err){
       console.log(err);   
    }
});
```

**Note:** imageMagick should be installed